# Android - MenuItem layout order affect java code

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried to create a menu with search and refresh button, but since refresh button will only be available at several activities, I want to set the visibility to false, and then add this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    item.setVisible(true);
    return true;
}
```

to the activity java

Using the below code, the menu is displayed properly, with refresh on the left and search on the right

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:visible="false"/>
```

But by reversing the item order,

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:title="Refresh"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:visible="false"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:menuCategory="system"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>
```

the refresh button/item will not appear.

While I have found the workaround and could proceed, this still puzzles me very much, and I haven't got any good explanation.

Why would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Eclipse?
I have seen a bug in Eclipse where simply changing the order of elements in an XML resource file would not recompile the file causing all kinds of weird things to happen.

I suggest you do a "Project > Clean" to make sure the resource identifiers get recreated from scratch.

Comment: I did that, but it still won't appear unless I swap the order.